# What is the Equivalent of Get-AzLog in az cli of Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to know the start/ stop history of my azure VM. My VM may be in start or stop state currently. But i want to see the historical logs to know when was VM started/ Stopped in past.
Could not find what is equivalent of get-AzLog

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but have a look at below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/activity-log?view=azure-cli-latest

```
az monitor activity-log list --resource-group <resource-group-name>
```

For help:

```
az monitor activity-log list --help
```